# autocomplete="username" does not work in iOS

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to get my iPhone to save the credentials when I login. But first of all the username field does not show the "Keychain" button to autofill my credentials. The password field does show this. I have tried all possible values for autocomplete for both fields but they never changed a thing (`on`, `off`, `username`, `current-password`).

I have also tried setting the type of the username to password. This did make the username activate `keychain`. But of course this is not what I want.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()" novalidate>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label position="stacked">Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="username" name="username" autocomplete="username" tabindex="1" (keyup.enter)="login()" required></ion-input>
      <ion-text *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.invalid && loginForm.touched" class="error" color="danger">Username is required</ion-text>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" tabindex="2" (keyup.enter)="login()" type="password" required></ion-input>
      <ion-text *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.invalid && loginForm.touched" class="error" color="danger">Password is required</ion-text>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-button color='primary' class="loginBtn" tabindex="3" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" ion-button type="submit" block float-right>
      {{ 'login.login' |translate }}&nbsp;
      <fa-icon icon='sign-in-alt'></fa-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </form>
```

Another thing is that tabindex also doesn't work. It doesn't activate the arrow buttons.

I have not been able to test this for android, but in chrome, the password manager does work. The tabindex doesn't (when I press tab it selects the area of the field before it selects the password field).

Comment: I was able to solve part of the problem by putting both fields into the same `ion-item`. However when I correctly fill in the fields, it still doesn't save the password to the keychain.